# Two computers show different numbers for same Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two computers and when I open the same Excel on both of them, they display different numbers. It looks like this:

[image]

First one shows number `135.05` while the other shows `135.059.003.051.757,00`. Both PC's have the same settings which are like this:

[image]

Does anyone knows of any other settings that might mess things up for me?

---

In the background there are a lot of macros running and I think this one might cause problems. It is called whenever worksheet is changed or activated or opened at the start. Task of this macro is to convert *"number stored as string"*:

```
Public Function remove_numbers_formated_as_text(ByVal sh As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long '''' arr's rows
    Dim j As Long '''' arr's columns
    
    Dim s As String
    Dim b As Boolean
    
    Set r = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    arr = r.Formula2

    '''' Iterate over a whole row and then proceed to next column
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If IsEmpty(arr(i, j)) = False Then
                
                '''' Check whether array mamber stores formula
                b = r(i, j).HasFormula
                If b = True Then GoTo A
                
                '''' If cell doesn't treat numbers as text and is a numeric value,
                '''' then this is definitely a measurement that somebody entered and
                '''' it is therefore converted to double.
                s = r(i, j).NumberFormat
                If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) And s <> "@" Then
                    arr(i, j) = CDbl(arr(i, j))
                End If
            
            End If
A:
        Next
    Next

    r.Formula2 = arr
    
End Function
```

Comment: The exact same file from the exact same folder path?  Something has to be off between the locale formatting between the two computers.

Comment: Yes. There are some macros running in the background. One macro uses `CDbl()` function to convert some values to double. I don't think macros are to blame though.

Comment: What values is the macro that calls `CDbl()` working on?

Comment: The locale of those two machines are different.  However, the two values are also not identical.  One is `135050003051757` and the other is `135.050003051757` one is being displayed as `135.050.003.051.757.00` and the other is being displayed as `135.05` and would have continued to display additional decimal digits if the field formatting was adjusted.  Provide the user locale for each user as a screenshot.

Comment: @Ramhound Where can I find user locale settings?

Comment: Yeah, the right-hand side shows 135 while the left-hand side shows 135 *trillion* in the formula. Formatting/display settings is not going to resolve that if they are both displaying the same (bit-identical) file.

Comment: @Yorik - The values not being the same is one problem, however, the locale is clearly treating one number with commas and the other as decmials to separate decmial values.

Comment: `Clock and Region` within Control Panel

Comment: @Ramhound So changes have to be made in the Windows OS you suggest?

Comment: @71GA - I am only asking for information to be provided you should be changing absolutely nothing at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value stored is the same, regardless, as it is the same file being opened (presumably from a network available to both computers), or the file and its reliably the same copy.

What could be wrong? I believe it to be related to the macros in a couple ways.

First, note that the macro looks to see if a value is stored by Excel as text or as numerical. (Not a VBA novice even, but the commenting in it makes that clear). It distinguishes because this is the logic it uses to distinguish between values in cells that were put there... somehow... but in any case, not by user entry, and values that WERE put there by user entry. So both Text and numerical values can be expected in all but the case of full entry by a user.

Secondly, if not Text, it ensures the not-Text value is a double for whatever purposes it has when it is running.

The first part matters a tremendous amount though... the fact that some or all of the values might be stored as and treated as Text, and then only as numerical values if and when Excel sees fit to do so.

How does that impact things? Excel looks at a value with numerical characters (and the separators) and compares its form to the Windows (or Apple) system settings to decide is this a number or not. If a value were stored as, say, `12345.34` Excel would almost certainly be willing to treat it as a numerical value in most ways even if the cell it were in were explicitly formatted as Text. To be sure, it would treat it as text when there is uncertainty, in a lookup for example, and that "honors" your direction to it when formatting the cell as text. But if you added `2` to it, it would be happy to do that as well, apparently considering you to desire that and "honoring" that choice as well.

However, if it were stored as, say, `12,345.34` and the cell marked as text, Excel would do the comparison to the operating system's settings for number-type values (numbers, dates, times...) and it might match one in which case it would do the above addition for you, or it might NOT match one in which case it would NOT do the above addition for you.

For this example, if your system settings used commas for integer separators and periods for the decimal separator, it WOULD see how to interpret it as a number and do the addition. If your integer separator were a period though, then it would not make sense to Excel as a number and it would fail to do the addition.

Before moving on, your information is a little contradictory. Your second pic is said to represent BOTH machines and shows integer separators as commas and the decimal separator as a period. But your first pic clearly shows the left machine having a comma for the decimal separator (15 characters, the most kept for a cell value by Excel matching the shown input value, plus displaying two zeros after a comma... those zeros can ONLY exist in the example as decimal places, as in a format of the sort `#.##0,00` and NOT the "opposite":  `#,@@0.00`. So no room for argument here.) unless it is a text display, but that doesn't fit the question so I discount the "unless."

That, and that which is above it, said, if you had a value stored AS TEXT in the form `135,050003051757` and opened the spreadsheet on a computer using commas for the integer separators and a period for the decimal separator, you would get the display you get on the left with a value in trillions followed by two (zero) decimal places. And Excel would strip the "odd" single comma from the cell so in the formula editor, you'd see exactly what the left side shows.

If, however, you opened it on a machine whose operating system's expectations were that the commas are decimal separators, Excel would see it as integer portion "135" and decimal portion "the rest" and display it according to the formatting so as "135.05"... and to make things more fun, because what is ACTUALLY the same between the two machines being the file and its cell formatting (which is, say, `#,##0.00` and so the "opposite" of that machine's operating system settings, but that only mattered when interpreting the TEXT value Excel felt itself to be presented with, not how it displays what it decides it truly is) is that the formatting for the cell itself, not the operating system (it's role is over), says to use a period for the decimal separator.

Which fully explains the two displayed results. The left one never realized there was a decimal place after the "135" and so displayed completely as an integer value that included, for display purposes only, two decimal places (that would ALWAYS be "00"). And the right one was interpreted properly, but then to confuse the issue, not displayed via the format used to interpret it, but by that to figure which bits go to which "part" and then those parts displayed by the cell formatting itself, which (confusing part) is at odds with the system settings.

There are any number of fixes available, but they all depend completely upon what you wish to do and what you can do. By "can do" I mean that you may have no influence at all over how the values come to be stored, so you can only solve it via things that deal with them coming like above and... handle the vagaries, which is surely easier said than done. By "wish to do" I mean things like change that macro to do something more involved with these values, especially that you'd not let it leave any as actual text. But also, formula approaches exist, and Excel even has a simple function explicitly for this kind of thing. But just like getting someone to use, say, "helper columns" when he does not wish to, what you wish (are willing) to do makes a monstrous difference to how to solve the problem. And above both "do's" is what your boss is willing to see done.

You should ask a second question for that part and give clear indication of what is available, both what you CAN affect, and what you are WILLING to affect, so we can help you out on that.

But the above is surely what is happening to you.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. I have to also mention that before the posted macro runs, another macro manually sets up the collumn number format to a decimal with a thousands separator as `,` and decimal separator as `.`. This is the VBA statement that does it's job: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"`.

Comment: I believe that I should 1st check which character is used by the system as a decimal specifier ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using)) and then set the number formatting as `#.##0,00` or `#,##0.00`. Maybee this would help in this situation...